# RefineryCMS image thumbnails not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I've got a RefineryCMS 3 application and in the backend the thumbnails for uploaded images are not showing up.

If I run the app in production mode on my development machine then the thumbnails show up. On the production machine the rails app is ran through passenger & apache and it fails.

I have copied my development copy to the production server for a test and ran the refinery project in development mode and I still get the same issue

```
rails s -b 192.168.200.215
```

Here is the standard output when I try and load the images area in refinery admin;

```
Started GET "/refinery/images" for 192.168.200.4 at 2016-03-01 15:32:25 +1100
Processing by Refinery::Admin::ImagesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>:en}
  Refinery::Authentication::Devise::User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "refinery_authentication_devise_users".* FROM "refinery_authentication_devise_users" WHERE "refinery_authentication_devise_users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "refinery_authentication_devise_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Refinery::Authentication::Devise::Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "refinery_authentication_devise_roles".* FROM "refinery_authentication_devise_roles" INNER JOIN "refinery_authentication_devise_roles_users" ON "refinery_authentication_devise_roles"."id" = "refinery_authentication_devise_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "refinery_authentication_devise_roles_users"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-acts-as-indexed-2.0.1/app/views/refinery/acts_as_indexed/admin/_search_header.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-core-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/admin/_search_header.html.erb (4.4ms)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "refinery_images"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "refinery_images"
  Refinery::Image Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "refinery_images".* FROM "refinery_images"  ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
  Refinery::Image::Translation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "refinery_image_translations".* FROM "refinery_image_translations" WHERE "refinery_image_translations"."refinery_image_id" IN (2)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-images-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/admin/images/_grid_view.html.erb (10.3ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-images-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/admin/images/_images.html.erb (14.5ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-images-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/admin/images/_records.html.erb (33.7ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-acts-as-indexed-2.0.1/app/views/refinery/acts_as_indexed/admin/_search.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-core-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/admin/_search.html.erb (4.8ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-images-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/admin/images/_actions.html.erb (17.0ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-images-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/admin/images/index.html.erb within layouts/refinery/admin (61.1ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-core-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/_html_tag.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-core-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/admin/_javascripts.html.erb (159.9ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-core-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/admin/_head.html.erb (232.9ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-core-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/_site_bar.html.erb (3.4ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-core-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/admin/_menu_item.html.erb (28.4ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-core-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/admin/_menu.html.erb (31.9ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-core-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/_no_script.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/refinerycms-core-3.0.1/app/views/refinery/_message.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 375ms (Views: 362.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/system/images/W1siZiIsIjIwMTYvMDMvMDEvN3lmN3ZpNDRtZV9hYWEuanBnIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCIxMzV4MTM1I2MiXV0/aaa.jpg?sha=7a0325c4ef12ef3d" for 192.168.200.4 at 2016-03-01 15:32:27 +1100
```

When it tries to get the /system/images/.... it fails in the web browser console. If I try and access that directly with the following

```
http://192.168.200.215:3000/system/images/W1siZiIsIjIwMTYvMDMvMDEvN3lmN3ZpNDRtZV9hYWEuanBnIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCIxMzV4MTM1I2MiXV0/aaa.jpg
```

I get the following error in the browser

```
Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The production server didn't have imagemagick installed.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

This fixed it.